# Can I use or import an Eclipse formatter in NetBeans?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

We have been using Eclipse for a long time. We have formatter for each of our projects. Now, some of us are moving to NetBeans. Is it possible to migrate / sync / import our Eclipse formatter to NetBeans? I tried importing an Eclipse project into NetBeans. It does not import the formatter we used.

Comment: I am in desperate need of a converter too. Syncing all settings by hand is pretty painful :-(

Comment: Formatter configuration is not a standard in Eclipse, every plug-in has its own formatter configuration format. Please specify what Eclipse/NetBeans plug-in you are talking about.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is **YES**. You can use eclipse code formatter in Netbeans, and enjoy using Netbeans. You need to download eclipse code formatter plugin from below location suitable to your Netbeans version, import your existing eclipse code formatter and ready to go

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50877/eclipse-code-formatter-for-java

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK There is no way to import the Eclipse formatting preferences into NetBeans. 
But if you use Maven you can use the [Maven2 Java Formatter Plugin](http://maven-java-formatter-plugin.googlecode.com/) which uses the Eclipse JDT features to format source files and integrates nicely with Maven projects. For a usage of current version 0.3.1 see [here](http://maven-java-formatter-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/site/0.3.1/usage.html).

This is a simple pom.xml using the formatter. Just put in any Java source file and run `mvn java-formatter:format`, your source should be formatted using the given Eclipse configuration file (where you have to provide the path to your own one).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.mackaz</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven.java.formatter.plugin.example</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>format</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                <configFile>./example-eclipse-code-format-config.xml</configFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT:**

A different approach is to invoke the Eclipse Code Formatter from commandline, (but takes a bit longer and is not nicely integrated into the Maven lifecycle), as described [here](http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/). 
You can format a sourcefile with it like this:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -verbose -nosplash -config example-eclipse-code-format-config.xml src/main/java/de/mackaz/FormatMe.java
```

(Also take a look at [this page](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/eclipse.html#formatter) where the author put that into a little script)

It should be easy to integrate one of those approaches into NetBeans. Either wrap those inside an Ant file and add that to your NetBeans commands, or write a little NetBeans plugin to add the action e.g. to the contextmenu (which is pretty easy, especially compared to writing Eclipse Plugins).

Answer (score 2):

I like NetBeans very much, but have the same problem with formatting.
I've found this maven plugin http://mvneclipsefmt.sourceforge.net/usage.html
Seems it can run eclipse formatter as maven goal. But I didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is a post on JBoss community which seems to address formating issues, it might be of some help; http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ImportFormattingRules

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[Eclipse Code Formatter for Java](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50877/eclipse-code-formatter-for-java)" NetBeans plugin it works with NetBeans 7.3 and .7.4 (but with a little problem!).

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that, as of Netbeans 7.3.1, a very clever fellow developed a Netbeans plugin that accepts Eclipse Formatter XML files. I have not tested this yet TBH, but I will be doing so in the very near future (as I am the only one at the office that prefers Netbeans over Eclipse, and I think my co-workers are conspiring to kill me due to git merge conflicts).

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/eclipse_formatter_for_netbeans_ide

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to use Eclipse's formatter as a plugin in Netbeas, [like it was done for IntelliJ](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6546)

Answer (score -1):

The following link may be of assistance http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/importexport-code-formatting it talks about sharing sharing settings.

Comment: Nop...It doesn't work. Importer does not import formatter settings. I have both, global and project specific settings. Neither of them is getting imported. Do you know any Netbeans reference where it says "it should have imported" ? Because i didn't see any specific mention for the same on NetBeans website.