# How can i make code formatting in netbeans and eclipse equal

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, import, export, code-formatting

How can i make code formatting standards equal in netbeans and eclipse equal. Also is ther is any way that i use eclipse code formatter in netbeans as for netbeans does not format javadocs comments

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071055/can-i-use-or-import-an-eclipse-formatter-in-netbeans

Comment: In particular answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20065809/1672678 for a NetBeans plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. You have these options:

1. Configure the formatters to the lowest common denominator (i.e. something that both of them can do). Not sure if that's possible because you can't "switch off" some options.
2. Eclipse has a feature called "Clean up". Select the project and it becomes available in the "Source" menu. This allows you to clean up certain aspects of a project: Unused imports, formatting, etc. So you save the work in Netbeans and then clean up the project once in a while in Eclipse.
3. Use an external formatter like [Jindent](http://www.jindent.com/) (Commercial but they have a non-commercial license). Create an Ant task to format the code.

Comment: can i download the ant version separately

Comment: Sorry, I haven't use Jindent before. But you can search for java formatter/indenter. There should be a couple of projects on SourceForge.

Comment: ALT+SHIFT+F (Tested in netbeans 7.2)

Answer (score 1):

If your project uses Maven, you can use this Maven plugin: http://code.google.com/p/maven-java-formatter-plugin/

It uses Eclipse formatting classes to do the format, and can be configured with your Eclipse formatting preferences, see the `configFile` property here: http://maven-java-formatter-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/site/0.3.1/format-mojo.html